# "Die Fragen, die er gefragt wird?" oder "Die Fragen, die ihn gefragt werden?" oder anders?

Tags: passive

Ich hätte im Betreff gerne eine allgemeinere Beschreibung meiner Frage genannt, allerdings fällt mir hierzu außer "vielleicht Passiv" noch nicht einmal der grammatikalische Fall ein, mit dem wir es hier zu tun haben.

Meine Frage ist, welche Form hier korrekt ist, wenn man ausdrücken möchte, dass es Fragen gibt und es gibt jemanden, dem diese Fragen gestellt werden. Allerdings, nicht unter Verwendung des Verbs "stellen" bzw. "gestellt" sondern mittels "fragen" bzw. "gefragt".

Heißt es also:

"Es sind die Fragen, die ihm gefragt werden." (vermutlich falsch) oder

"Es sind die Fragen, die ihn gefragt werden." oder

"Es sind die Fragen, die er gefragt wird." ?

Oder kann man keine dieser Varianten korrekt verwenden? Falls doch, welche Variante ist hier richtig und welcher grammatikalische Fall ist das hier?

Das im folgenden Forumseintrag diskutierte ist hiermit eventuell verwandt: https://grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?821-Passivkonstruktion-von-quot-fragen-quot-Subjekt-im-Nominativ

Comment: Ob *eine Frage zu fragen* wirklich grammatikalisch **falsch** ist, wie Hubert in seiner Antwort ausführt, sei mal dahingestellt, schlechter Stil wäre es aber auf jeden Fall. Wenn Du - warum auch immer - unbedingt vermeiden willst, eine Frage zu *stellen*, kannst Du sie höchstens noch (zur allgemeinen Beantwortung) in den Raum *werfen*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <s>Es sind die Fragen, die ihm gefragt werden.</s>

Falsch, denn das Verb *fragen* hat kein Dativobjekt.

Das Verb *fragen* hat jedoch zwei Akkusativobjekte, und genau daher stammt wohl auch die Verwirrung. Um die Fälle besser auseinanderhalten zu können, verwende ich ein leicht abgewandeltes Beispiel.

> Er fragt mich immer denselben Mist.
>
> Er wird von mir immer denselben Mist gefragt.

Hier sieht man, dass die normale Regel des Passivs – das Akkusativobjekt wird zum Subjekt – für das zweite Akkusativobjekt nicht gilt! Vergleiche

> Er geht immer denselben Weg.
>
> Derselbe Weg wird immer von ihm gegangen.

Man kann sich allerdings aussuchen, welches nun das Akkusativobjekt sein soll, das in der Passivkonstruktion zum Subjekt wird. Nimmt man das Zweite, kommt

> Derselbe Mist wird mich immer von ihm gefragt.

dabei heraus.

Daran sieht man, dass die Sätze

> Es ist immer derselbe Mist, den er gefragt wird.
>
> Es ist immer derselbe Mist, der ihn gefragt wird.

beide grammatisch richtig sind. Es ist nur eine Frage des Blickwinkels, welches der beiden Akkusativobjekte nun kraft des Passivs zum Subjekt gekürt wird.

Comment: Ich hätte "Ich werde immer denselben Mist von ihm gefragt" als *korrekter* gegenüber "derselbe Mist wird mich immer von ihm gefragt" angesehen. Denn "wird mich immer von ihm" klingt sehr komisch in meinen Ohren.

Comment: *Von ihm wird mich immer derselbe Mist gefragt.* – Das klingt sehr natürlich. Auch hier ist *derselbe Mist* das Subjekt.

Comment: In der Reihenfolge: ja, für mich auch. Anders rum sortiert hakt in meinem Kopf. K, dann bin ich grammatikalisch raus.

Comment: @Janka vielen Dank für deine Antwort. Heißt das also, dass - auf mein Beispiel bezogen - sowohl "Es sind die Fragen, die ihn gefragt werden." als auch "Es sind die Fragen, die er gefragt wird." korrekt ist und beide Varianten semantisch dieselbe Bedeutung haben?

Comment: Sie sind beide grammatisch korrekt, aber semantisch leicht unterschiedlich. Im einen Fall sind die Fragen auch im Relativsatz das Subjekt, im anderen das zweite Akkusativobjekt. Das ändert meines Erachtens den Blickwinkel.

Comment: In einer kurzen Recherche (siehe Kommentar unter Huberts Antwort) habe ich nur Beispiele gefunden, in denen die Person im Passiv Subjekt wurde. Deshalb bin ich nicht sicher, ob *mich wurden Fragen gefragt* tatsächlich grammatisch ist.

Comment: Einen Umweg über Ausweichfragen zu gehen finde ich nicht verkehrt, aber auf die Ausgangsfrage, ob man jemanden Fragen fragen kann, kommst Du gar nicht zurück. "Ich frage jemanden eine Frage"? "Ich frage jemanden nach der Uhrzeit/dem Weg", ja. "Ich stelle jemandem eine Frage" - auch ja. Aber "ich frage jemanden eine Frage"? "Ich frage jemanden" Punkt.

Answer (score 1):

Das Verb *»fragen«* kann zwar mit zwei Akkusativobjekten verwendet werden, aber für diese Objekte gibt es Einschränkungen:

> Ich frage *dich* **etwas.**
> Der Lehrer fragt *den Schüler* **viele Details.**
> Weißt du, wer das war, der uns so schräg angequatscht hat? - Nein, **das** frage ich *mich* auch.

Eines der beiden Akkusativobjekte stellt die befragte Person dar (oben in *kursiver Schrift* gekennzeichnet), das andere ist eine generische Bezeichnung für das, was als Antwort erwartet wird. Da man als Antwort aber keine Fragen erwartet, kann man auch keine Fragen fragen.

Dinge, die man fragen kann, und somit als jenes Akkusativobjekt infrage kommen, das nicht die befragte Person bezeichnet, sind beispielsweise:

- fünf rechte Nebenflüsse der Donau in Österreich

  > Wie war der Geografietest? - Ganz ok. Aber der Prof hat *fünf rechte Nebenflüsse der Donau in Österreich* gefragt, aber die meisten von uns haben nur drei oder vier gewusst.
- die Aggregatszustände

  > Der Lehrer hat den Prüfling *die Aggregatszustände* gefragt.
- viele persönliche Dinge

  > Der Anwalt fragte seinen Klienten *viele persönliche Dinge.*

Alle genannte Beispiele kann man als Überschriften für Aufzählungen verstehen, und diese Auszählungen werden als Antwort erwartet (im ersten Beispiel z.B. "Enns, Traun, Ybbs, Wien, Fischa", im zweiten "fest, flüssig, gasförmig"). Nachdem aber niemand als Antwort auf eine Frage eine Liste von weiteren Fragen erwartet, gehört der Begriff "Fragen" (oder im Singular: "eine Frage") nicht zu den Dingen, die man fragen kann.

**Fragen werden nicht gefragt, sondern gestellt.**

Zu ergänzen ist noch, dass das Verb *fragen* viel häufiger zusammen mit einem Präpositionalobjekt anstelle des zweiten Akkusativobjekts verwendet wird, wobei die bei weitem häufigste Präposition das Wort *nach* ist:

> Der Lehrer hat den Prüfling *nach den Aggregatszuständen* gefragt.
> Der Anwalt fragte seinen Klienten *nach vielen persönlichen Dingen.*
> Der Tourist fragt *nach dem Weg.*
> Leon fragt seine Mutter *um Erlaubnis.*

Dass das Wort *Fragen* nicht als Akkusativobjekt für das Verb *fragen* infrage kommt, erkennt man auch, wenn man es in ein Präpositionalobjekt (bestehend aus "nach" + Dativobjekt) umwandelt:

> falsch: Tom wird **Fragen** gefragt. (Akkusativobjekt)
> falsch: Tom wird **nach Fragen** gefragt. (Präpositionalobjekt)

Nachdem also *"Fragen fragen"* falsch ist, geht die ursprünglich gestellte Frage von einer falschen Prämisse aus und ist daher nicht beantwortbar.

Comment: *Und wenn alle Fragen gefragt waren* ([Süddeutsche](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/sport/tour-de-france-emanuel-buchmann-1.4542569)) *Und wenn man solche Fragen gefragt wird* ([DLF](https://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/filmproduzent-marcus-loges-ueber-a-hidden-life-das.2168.de.html?dram:article_id=449732)) […] *bin ich auch solche Fragen gefragt worden* ([Nürnberger Prozeß](http://www.zeno.org/Geschichte/M/Der+N%C3%BCrnberger+Proze%C3%9F/Hauptverhandlungen/Einhundertsechsundsechzigster+Tag.+Freitag,+28.+Juni+1946/Nachmittagssitzung))

Comment: "Der Prof. hat fünf Nichten Mozarts in Österreich gefragt" - mir scheint, der Professor steht aber noch an den 5 Nebenflüssen d. Donau und wartet auf deren Antwort. Muss es nicht heißen "hat 5 Nebenflüsse der Donau abgefragt" oder "uns zu/nach (den) 5 Nebenflüssen befragt"? "Hat den Prüfling die Aggregatszustände gefragt." Auch hier Protest. "Hat nach den AZuständen gefragt" oder hat "die AZustände abgefragt" oder "zu den AZuständen gefragt", oder?

Comment: Also *Tom wird nach Fragen gefragt.* geht aber schon - dann nämlich, wenn Tom als Redakteur bei "Wer wird Millionär" arbeitet und sich bis heute ein paar neue Fragen hätte ausdenken sollen ;-)

Comment: @userunknown: Ich zitiere aus meinem Posting: *»Zu ergänzen ist noch, dass das Verb fragen viel häufiger zusammen mit einem Präpositionalobjekt anstelle des zweiten Akkusativobjekts verwendet wird, wobei die bei weitem häufigste Präposition das Wort nach ist«* Thema der Frage waren aber Akkusativobjekte.

Answer (score 1):

Die ersten zwei Sätze sind falsch, der dritte stilistisch an der Grenze.

> Heißt es also:
>
> - "Es sind die Fragen, die ihm gefragt werden." (vermutlich falsch)
>     oder
> - "Es sind die Fragen, die ihn gefragt werden." oder
> - "Es sind die Fragen, die er gefragt wird."?

Ja, a) ist falsch. "Es sind die Fragen, die ihm gestellt werden." kann man mit "ihm" fragen.
Auch b) ist falsch. "Es sind die Fragen, die ihn nachts umtreiben." kann man mit "ihn" fragen. 
Punkt c) knirscht, aber gesetzt den Fall, Du hast 10 Fragen in Umschlägen für einen Quizkandidaten. Auf der Bühne werden jetzt 3 Umschläge von den zehnen gezogen, und die enthalten die Fragen, die er schließlich - gefragt wird/gestellt bekommt/beantworten soll.

Fragen fragen ist doppelt gemoppelt und kein guter Stil.

Er wird gefragt *wie spät es ist*, wo es nach Rom oder *zum Bahnhof geht*, oder wie der Großvater mütterlicherseits von Heinz dem IV *hieß*. Aber *er wird eine Frage gefragt*?

> Was fandet Ihr in seinem Notizbuch?
>   **Es sind die Fragen, die ihm gestellt werden.**

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort.
Mich würde insbesondere interessieren, ob hierbei > "Es sind die Fragen, die ihn gefragt werden." oder
> "Es sind die Fragen, die er gefragt wird." ? die zweitere Möglichkeit auch richtig wäre...